# @observable on numeric type doesn't create observable

Tags: javascript, mobx

When trying to use @observable on a numeric type it doesn't create an Observable. This causes the problem where the computed value gets recalculated every time it is fetched.  I don't want the computed value to get recalculated unless the inputs have changed, what is the problem here?

https://jsbin.com/mofirujixu/1/edit?html,js,console

```
class Square {
  @observable width = 2;

  @computed get area() {
    console.log('calc area');
    return this.width * this.width;
  }
}

const square = new Square();
//prints out 'calc area' each time
console.log(square.area);
console.log(square.area);
console.log(square.area);
```

Comment: Keeping all those unobserved computed values around would kill garbage collection. [**This question**](https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx/issues/161#issuecomment-355187045) and answer might give some insight.

Comment: Thanks that does accurately describe my issue.  The part that still confuses me though is why it seems accepted that these computed values recalculate.  I could use rxjs to set up state calculations that only recalculate when the inputs change, but I was hoping mobx would be simpler.

Comment: Ah, interesting. I've only used MobX with React and friends, which comes with separate library specific view bindings, which essentially makes the components into observers, so this problem does not come up. I actually don't know how to go around it in Angular. Have you stumbled upon [**this**](https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx-angularjs)?

Comment: I have not tried that out yet, that could be what I need.  This helps a lot, once again I really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

MobX only caches the resulting value of a computed if it is being observed by one or more observers. It is implemented this way to decrease memory footprint and to allow the garbage collector to do its job.

You could use a simple `autorun` before the logs to see this in action:

```
class Square {
  @observable width = 2;

  @computed get area() {
    console.log('calc area');
    return this.width * this.width;
  }
}

const square = new Square();

autorun(() => {
  square.area;
  // square.area is now observed by one observer, 
  // and will not be re-calculated for subsequent reads.
});
console.log(square.area);
console.log(square.area);
console.log(square.area);
```